# Programmatically add c# class to project

Tags: c#, code-generation

How can I add C# class to my project programmatically in design mode? (like code generator)

Comment: Please specify your development environment. Is it Visual Studio 2010 Professional? Express? ...etc.  The tool you're using to compile the project dictates the easiest approach.

Comment: You mean add reference to some external class?

Comment: i'm using vs 2008 Professional

Comment: Any news for 2019 or 2022?

Answer (score 1):

You could use macro.
It can do anything to VS IDE.

Comment: but i have no idea about macros

Comment: Don't think macros will help in this case, take a look at the comment to Steve's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can [create a Add-In](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/80493a3w%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for Visual Studio. Look at [this sample code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228774%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) from Microsoft which programmatically creates a project item (class).